# Returning name of list where the string is found

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently able to complete the task I want by using a large number of for loops, however I feel like there should be a simpler way.

I want my prog to return the name of the list which contains the word that was found in a string.  I am currently doing:

```
my_car = ["blue","ford"]
dads_car = ["green","audi"]
car = input('Tell me either the make or colour of your car: ').lower()
whos_car = ""
for word in my_car:
    if word in car:
        whos_car = "my_car"
    else:
        whos_car = "unknown"
for word in dads_car:
    if word in car:
        whos_car = "dads_car"
    else:
        whos_car = "unknown"
print(whos_car)
```

But what I want to do is write a for loop which goes through each list, and whichever list contains the word, return the list name.
This will not work, but hopefully it will make it clearer:

```
for word in my_car,dads_car:
    if word in car:
        whos_car = the list name it found it in...
    else:
        whos_car = "Unknown"
```

Hope that makes sense.

Many thanks!

Comment: what if the car is present in both lists?

Comment: probably it is just a copy/paste typo but you are not _calling_ `lower` here.

Comment: This code prints "my_car" for  "blueajdsjada" since "blue" in that input. Is that intended behaviour?

Comment: Sorry Van Peer, should have made that clearer.  If present in both lists, then it should show the first list it found in.
Lafexlos, it was a typo - thanks for pointing out, will fix now

Comment: @Lafexlos that is not the intended behviour for the final script, but it was a problem I was going to research and tackle next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update after clarification

Use a dictionary and a function:

```
def get_list(cars, car):
    car_parts = car.split()
    for list_name, car_info in cars.items():
        for item in car_info:
            if item in car_parts:
                return list_name
    return 'unknown'

my_car = ["blue","ford"]
dads_car = ["green","audi"]
cars = {'my_car': my_car, 'dads_car': dads_car}
car = 'the car green'
print(get_list(cars, car))
```

Now, if you set:

```
car = 'the car green'
```

it prints:

```
dads_car
```

but:

```
car = 'light-green truck'
```

prints:

```
unknown
```

### Old attempts

Looks like a good use for a dictionary:

```
my_car = ["blue","ford"]
dads_car = ["green","audi"]

cars = {'my_car': my_car, 'dads_car': dads_car}

car = 'green'

for list_name, car_info in cars.items():
    if car in car_info:
        print(list_name)
        break
else:
    print('unknown')
```

Now, if you set:

```
car = 'green'
```

it prints:

```
dads_car
```

but:

```
car = 'yellow'
```

prints:

```
unknown
```

You can add as many items to `cars` as you like without changing the code. So no large number of `for` loops.

> If present in both lists, then it should show the first list it found in.

You break out of the loop as soon as you find a match.
The code under `else:` will only be reached if the `break` was executed.
Starting from Python 3.6. dictionaries keep the order they where built with.
Therefore, `my_car` will be searched first.

Alternative solution with different logic:

```
my_car = ["blue","ford"]
dads_car = ["green","audi"]

cars = {'my_car': my_car, 'dads_car': dads_car}

found = False
for list_name, car_info in cars.items():
    for item in car_info:
        if item in car:
            print(list_name)
            found = True
            break
    if found:
        break
else:
    print('unknown')
```

Now, if you set:

```
car = 'light-green'
```

it prints:

```
dads_car
```

Or shorter as a function:

```
def get_list(cars, car):
    for list_name, car_info in cars.items():
        for item in car_info:
            if item in car:
                return list_name
    return 'unknown'

print(get_list(cars, car))
```

Comment: Hi Mike,
Thanks for this, seems the most efficient.  However, i need to be looking for car_info in car, rather than car in car_info.  When swapping I get this:

    'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list

Any ideas on what I can do here?

Comment: Do you want  `light-green` for `car`  to give you  `dads_car`  as result?

Comment: No, i just want it to look for each list item within the car value

Comment: But the car value is a string. In side the car value would mean each individual character.

Comment: What's wrong with entering `green` and getting `dads_car` as result?

Comment: I see what you mean.  In actual fact the car string would be "the car green".  So I want to check to see if any of the individual values in each list exist within the car string, and if so, return the list name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162532/discussion-between-mike-muller-and-rlou).

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of [locals()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#locals):

```
def lookup(query):
    my_car = ["blue","ford"]
    dads_car = ["green","audi"]

    for name, vals in locals().items():
        #  you need a condition to filter the variables you want to search in!
        if name.endswith('_car') and query in vals:
            return name
    return 'unknown'

result = lookup('green')
print(result)

result = lookup('green2')
print(result)
```

Prints:

```
dads_car
unknown
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to not change the value of `whos_car` when it is not found in a list, a search the second list only if the word was not found in first one. Your code could simply become:

```
my_car = ["blue","ford"]
dads_car = ["green","audi"]
car = input('Tell me either the make or colour of your car: ').lower()
whos_car = None          # None is more "Pythonic"
for word in my_car:
    if word in car:
        whos_car = "my_car"
        break            # no need to continue looping
if whos_cas is None:     # don't search second list if word has already be found
    for word in dads_car:
        if word in car:
            whos_car = "dads_car"
            break
if whos_car is None: whos_car = "unknow"   # if we haven't found anything...
print(whos_car)
```

Comment: This has reminded me of break, so thank you very much (you may be able to tell i'm new to all of this).  However,  my actual script has considerably more lists than my_car and dads_car so I am not sure if this will be suitable.  really do appreciate it though Serge!

Answer (score 0):

My solution is the following and it should be pretty easy to understand:

You can also use as suggested 2 breaks after whos_car to end the forloop (in case you make those list bigger)

Code:

```
my_car = ["blue", "ford"]
dads_car = ["green" , "audi"]

car = str.lower(input('Tell me either the brand or colour of your car: '))

for element in zip(my_car,dads_car):
    if car in element[0]:
        whos_car = "mine car now"
    elif car in element[1]:
        whos_car = "dads car"
    else:
        whos_car = "uknown"

print(whos_car)
```

OUTPUT:

`user@user:~$ python3 script.py
Tell me either the brand or colour of your car: FORD
mine car now`

Answer (score 0):

```
my_car = ["blue","ford"]
dads_car = ["green","audi"]
car = input('Tell me either the make or colour of your car: ').lower()
whos_car = "unknown"
for owner, lst in (('my_car', my_car), ('dads_car', dads_car)):
    for word in lst:
        if word == car:
            whos_car = owner
            break
print(whos_car)
```

That is quite close to what you requested. So owner and lst are assiged values from each tuple that the for loop reads from. The use of break ensures no overwrite of whos_car once the owner is found.